# display part of an image and hide the rest using CCScene

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

ok so i have the following code :

```
CCScene * timerLayer = [CCScene node];
[timerLayer setContentSize:CGSizeMake(50, 36)];
timerLayer.position = ccp(100, 260);
if(![self getChildByTag:777]){
    [self addChild:timerLayer z:20 tag:777];
}


timerGraphic = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"timer_small.png"];
timerGraphic.position = ccp(0,0);
timerLayer.contentSize = CGSizeMake(50, 36);

if(![timerLayer getChildByTag:779]){
    [timerLayer addChild:timerGraphic z:19 tag:779];
}
```

as you can see, I am making a `timerLayer` Scene, and I have resized the the scene to 50x, 36y. and I also have timerGraphic, and I just want to show 50x 36y of this sprite so i tried resizing the scene, but its not working... its showing the entire image all together!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CCScene node can not be used to clip images. You can either use a [Clipping Node](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/01/cocos2d-gem-clippingnode/) or in your case simply change the texture rect to only display that part of the image that's inside the rectangle:

```
[timerGraphic setTextureRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 36)];
```

Note: be sure that the rect is within the image's bounds!

Comment: thanks alot, do you know how I can make the corners round? is that possible?

Comment: you could overlay a "round corner" image